# Testing custom async validator

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test that my form control is invalid when my mock custom async validator returns a key value pair.

This is the mock validator I have created:

```
export async function mockUniqueEmailValidatorFn(control: AbstractControl) {
    const existingEmailAddresses = ['TestEmail@gmail.com'];
    if(existingEmailAddresses.includes(control.value)) {
        return of({'emailUniquenessViolated': true})
            .pipe(
                first()
            );
    } else {
        return of(null);
    }
```

This is the unit test I have setup:

```
 it('should be invalid when email has already been used to create an account', () => {
                    //Arrange
                    component.registerForm.controls['email'].clearAsyncValidators;
  component.registerForm.controls['email'].addAsyncValidators(mockUniqueEmailValidatorFn);
                //Act
                component.registerForm.controls['email'].setValue("TestEmail@gmail.com");
                fixture.detectChanges();
                console.log(component.registerForm.controls['email']);
                
                //Assert
                expect(component.registerForm.controls['email'].invalid).toBeTruthy();
            });
```

The test is failing as the invalid property on the email form control is false. Any ideas why this is happening?

A few odd things I have noticed. The form control is both not valid and not invalid at the time of me logging the control to the console:

[image]

Also, the status of the form control is `"PENDING"` at the time of the logging the form control to the console, even though I have used the `first()` rxjs operator which should complete the observable once it emits it's first value:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the status is still `PENDING` because we may need to use `fakeAsync/tick`.

Try the following (Pay attention to !!):

```
// !! Add fakeAsync to the callback here.
 it('should be invalid when email has already been used to create an account', fakeAsync(() => {
                    //Arrange

// !! You most likely need to call this method (add () to the end)                    component.registerForm.controls['email'].clearAsyncValidators();
  component.registerForm.controls['email'].addAsyncValidators(mockUniqueEmailValidatorFn);
                //Act
                component.registerForm.controls['email'].setValue("TestEmail@gmail.com");
                fixture.detectChanges();
                // !! Call tick for the subscription to have completed and 
                // so you can start your assertions
                tick();
                console.log(component.registerForm.controls['email']);
                
                //Assert
                expect(component.registerForm.controls['email'].invalid).toBeTruthy();
            }));
```

Comment: Hi AliF50. I've attempted to add `FakeAsync` and `Tick` but the same issues still persists (I.e. Invalid property is still false, form control is still both not valid and not invalid at the same time and the status gets stuck on `"PENDING"`)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure then.